# Trying to get latest folder name in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, ms-release-management

I am attempting to run nuint console from powershell to run some Selenium Tests on my app.

The commmand in Powershell is as below:

```
$command = 'D:\tools\NUnitTestRunner\nunit3-console.exe "\\myserver\Drops\MyProj\MyApp_20170214.1\App.Selenium.Tests.dll"'
iex $command
```

This works as expected.  However, the piece I want to change is in the double "".  I want to run my Regression Test when a release is dropped to the folder a new App.Selenium.Test.dll will get dropped - with the Folder MyApp_DATE.DropNumber will change.

So I may have under the path \myserver\Drops\MyProj\ folders like below:

```
MyApp_20170214.1
MyApp_20170214.2
MyApp_20170214.3
MyApp_20170214.4
```

I want to get the latest folder dynamically and put it into the command rather than having to go in each time and hard code it.  This is what I have tried:

```
$logFile = "$PSScriptRoot\NunitLog.txt"
$dir = "\\myserver\Drops\MyProj\"

#Go get the latest Folder Name
$latest = Get-ChildItem $dir Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 1

#remove old log file
if(Test-Path $logFile) { Remove-Item $logFile }

"Starting Selenium Tests" | Out-File $logFile -Append
$latest.name | Out-File $logFile -Append

#Start nUnit Console and pass argument which is the latest path to the dll of the tests
#$command = 'D:\tools\NUnitTestRunner\nunit3-console.exe "$latest.name"'
```

However, it isn't outputting the folder name to the logFile or running it in the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was missing a pipe between dir & Where, when populating $latest. Also, the $command line should have double quotes round the entire string, as PowerShell treats it as a string literal when wrapped in single quotes. To include double quotes in the resulting command, we add a backtick before them. We also wrap `$latest.name` with `$()` to allow PowerShell to evaluate - otherwise we end up with the folder name having `.name` at the end of it.

```
$logFile = "$PSScriptRoot\NunitLog.txt"
$dir = "\\myserver\Drops\MyProj\"

#Go get the latest Folder Name
$latest = Get-ChildItem $dir | Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 1

#remove old log file
if(Test-Path $logFile) { Remove-Item $logFile }

"Starting Selenium Tests" | Out-File $logFile -Append
$latest.name | Out-File $logFile -Append

#Start nUnit Console and pass argument which is the latest path to the dll of the tests
#$command = "D:\tools\NUnitTestRunner\nunit3-console.exe `"$($latest.name)`""
```

Comment: Cool. Glad to help :)